# Moving Average in MS SQL?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm not sure what this would be called as searching for the term "moving average" is not producing what it is that I'm looking to do...

I have a table in MSSQL which contains a series of weather observations, these observations are taken at irregular intervals.

I want to create a stored procedure in SQL which will take a time as an input variable, and then select the nearest before and after observations, and calculate an approximation of the measurements at that input time and return these values.

I understand I could create an average of the 2 rows, but if I input a time of 07:24 and there is an observation at 07:25, the measurements are going to be closer to the recorded value than the average.

[image]

In my head, I think I know how to do it, but its messy: -

- Calculate difference between measurement times (minutes/int)
- Calculate difference between measurement values (int/float)
- Divide times/values to give a measurement per minute
- Calculate difference between earliest time and input variable (minutes/int)
- Multiply measurement per minute by input var difference (int/float)
- Add the value from the step above to the earliest time measurement variable to produce the returned value

So my concerns are:

- Is this too advanced or complex a function for SQL?
- If not, will it be a very long and messy stored procedure?

I'm not looking for somebody to do it for me, I want to learn, any pointers, advice, duplicate posts or sample code snippets would be greatly received and studied.

Comment: It would be nice if you add some sample data and desired output. from you description seems you need LAG/LEAD-functions to use

Comment: I have added a screenshot of my weather table. I have no issues selecting the before and after rows, I've done that through embedded queries and a UNION.

I was looking more for advice and guidance on the calculating side of the query

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: The reason people want it as text is because it's much easier to copy into tools like https://dbfiddle.uk. An image means it needs to be manually typed, and if it's a lot of data no-one's going to bother

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you want to do is a like a weighted average. This should be relatively straightforward to achieve in a stored proc or user defined function, though obviously will only work for numeric observations, not text ones.

First we get the observations directly before and after the specified time. Lets call these `A` and `B`.

Then we work out the number of seconds between the time of `A` and the specified time (lets call this `X`) and the number of seconds between the times of `A` and `B` (lets call this `Y`).

The calculation `X / Y` will give us a percentage of "distance" between `A` and the specified time, so `(1 - X / Y)` will give us the "closeness" to `A` which we can use as a weightings in the weighted average. The inverse applies to `B`.

So the final calculation is:
`A x (1 - X / Y) + B x (X / Y)`

For example, if the specified time is 7:25, and the closest observations are 32 at 7:20 and 30 at 7:30, we have the following:

- `A` = `32`, `B` = `30`, `X` = `10`, `Y` = `20`
- `X / Y` = `1 - X / Y` = `0.5`
- `Output` = `31`

Comment: Brenton, thank you so much.

In terms of categorical values, I could encode these as integer 0 and 1,  using the same calculation and rounding, calculate whether the final result will be 0 or 1 then decode back to the respective categorical value - that would work wouldn't it?

Comment: Yeah good idea, that would get you whichever value was closest.

Comment: Brenton, I appear to have hit a lamppost...

With the FromTime as 0630, ToTime as 0725, Measurement Time as 0720, FromVar as 80 and ToVar as 88, that gives me: A = 80, B = 88, X = 50 (minutes) & Y = 55 (minutes) and the calculation is giving me a value of 80.7272... I'd expect it to be nearer to 88, maybe 87.272. I dont know how to change my reply to a way that formats its better so hope you understand

Comment: Ah, I think I may have put the weightings around the wrong way. Could you try this instead: A x (1 - X / Y) + B x (X / Y). I'll update my answer...

Comment: Hi Brenton, apologies for the delay - been having some time out. Just to confirm, this works perfectly. Thanks very much for your effort and support :)